# Binding key event and click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function :

```
this.changeItemQty = function (e, cartObject) {
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
    var qty = $(e.currentTarget).val();

    $('#update' + id).text("Update");

    if (e.which === 13 || $('#update' + id).data('clicked')) {
        doFunction();
    }
}
```

I want to execute `doFunction()` whenever user presses key Enter or click on a `update` text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you also post relevant HTML? When `changeItemQty` getting called?

Comment: @plalx : I called it in the action of backbone view : `qtyChange : function(e){ obj.changeItemQty(e,obj); }`